# Acceder a la informacion de un input dentro de una tabla con $(this).parents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla html, y por cada registro se tiene un boton, unos datos planos y un input.
cuando se presiona el boton, quisiera poder capturar el dato del input que se encuentra en otra columna.
pero no he podido lograrlo.

tengo un metodo asi:

```
 function metodo(obj)
        {
        
        //var id2 = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        //var data = $(obj).parents("tr").find("number").value;
        var data = $(this).parents("tr").find("number").value;
        console.log(data);
        
        }
```

He puesto un ejemplo completo aqui:

https://jsfiddle.net/dzsmk81f/1/

lo que pasa es que no entiendo muy bien el uso de parents, para acceder a los atributos que contiene, si alguien maneja bien este tema y me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceria mucho.
gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es solo usar `parents` (El método traversa los nodos parientes). Tienes la idea correcta, pero estás mezclando varias cosas:

Estás pasando `this` como argumento, pero en la función no usas el argumento. La función `find` de jQuery toma un selector, en este caso `input` (no 'number'). Y la función para tomar el valor en jQuery se llama `val()`, (`value` es un atributo HTML)

Reemplaza tu función de JS en tu fiddle por:

```
 function metodo(obj)
        {
            var data = $(obj).parents('tr').find('input').val();
            console.log(data)
        
        }
```

Comment: En mi proyecto principal, logré capturarlo de la siguiente manera:
var data = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="number"]').val();
muchisimas gracias, pos su valiosa ayuda.

una ultima pregunta, como podria yo en vez de leer, insertarle un dato a ese input?
es decir:

let dato = 1;
var data = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="number"]').val('dato');

¿deberia funcionar?

Comment: Con gusto. Si, el argumento que le pases a `val()` ingresa el valor en el campo.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar `.closest('tr')` para acceder a la fila, comienza la búsqueda desde el elemento actual, mientras que `.parents('tr')` inicia desde el primer ancestro; dependiendo de cada caso, el resultado puede ser diferente.

El problema no es como accedes al padre, sino al elemento deseado, donde debes usar un selector CSS válido:

```
var data = $(this).parents("tr").find("number").value;
```

El selector especificado en `.find()` es `number`, por lo que jQuery buscará un elemento con esa etiqueta y no existe, porque tienes:

```
<td><input type="number" id="fname1" name="fname1"></td>
```

El único selector que puedes usar para este caso es por etiqueta y tipo:

```
var data = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="number"]').val();
```

Por cierto, en tu pregunta puedes agregar código funcional como el de *jsfiddle*, solo haz clic en el icono `<>`, a un lado del de imagen y tienes las secciones para agregar HTML, CSS, Javascript y ver el resultado.

Comment: muchas gracias, tu 'input[type="number"]',, me fue de muchisima ayuda, finalmente despues de varias pruebas, lo que mejor me sirvio fue, el parents, tendré que hacer mas pruebas con el closest. de verdad muchisimas gracias.